# Interface and Covariant return type

Tags: java, inheritance

Following code is not compiling and is giving following error at  `Line 1`

> The return type is incompatible with B.m1()

```
interface A {
    Object m1(); 
}

interface B {
    String m1();
}

abstract class C implements A,B {
    @Override
    public Object m1() //Line 1
    {
        return new Object();
    }
}

class D extends C {

    @Override
    public String m1() {
        return "";
    }

}
```

Now, my query is both `Object` and `String` are `covariant` and `class C` is abstract class then why this compilation error is there although I am implementing both `A` and `B` interface methods.

Comment: Nothing like that if you put void as a return type it will work fine

Comment: No, Issues please try to find the answer and clear my doubts.. :)

Comment: `C` doesn't work. Because if `C` is a `B` then I expect back a `String` from `m1`. So `B` works as an `A`, but **not** vice versa. So `C` doesn't work. See [Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: it is not about which doesn't work it's about why it wont work?

Comment: @BoristheSpider-- My question is - C is abstract and I am only implementing a covariant type of object leaving other for subclass. Why is this error.

Comment: Because you are not doing that - it's _contravariant_.

Comment: @BoristheSpider- Kindly explain in answer so that we all can see what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C` doesn't work.

Because if `C` is a `B` then I expect back a `String` from `m1`. So `B` works as an `A`, but not vice versa. So `C` doesn't work.

```
final A a = new C(){};
final Object res = a.m1(); //fine, `m1` returns an `Object`.

final B b = new C(){};
final String res = b.m1(); //bang
```

Here we see that `B` returns a `String` from `m1()`, but your implementation returns `Object`. The compile cannot allow this to happen.

See the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If `C` *is a* `B` then everywhere I have a `B` I should be able to replace it with a `C` - in your example that is not the case.

---

This would work - can you see why?

```
abstract class C implements A, B {
    @Override
    public String m1() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you are right , this is working ...:) strange I need to check and understand your answer accordingly

Comment: I request you to please tell us why second case is working, not able to understand

Comment: @LoneWolf I think it would be more useful for you to work that out yourself. Read about Liskov then apply the same logic I did above.

Comment: " If `C` is a `B` then everywhere I have a `B` I should be able to replace it with a `C`". Not necessarily because a `B` can be a `C`  or any child of `B`. Should it not be  : " If `C` is a `B` then everywhere I have a `C` I should be able to replace it with a `B`"  ?

Comment: @davidxxx you cannot generally replace every instance of a subclass with the superclass - for example if you have `ArrayList` you cannot replace them all with `Collection`. But the reverse _should_ be true is `ArrayList` _is a_ `Collection`.